# How do I run a directory compare operation from TortoiseGit?

Tags: git, compare, tortoisegit, beyondcompare

The diff program BeyondCompare has a directory compare feature where you can select two folders and have it run a side-by-side comparison on all files within those folders that have the same filenames, and then look at individual files that it flags as showing differences.  TortoiseSVN has a way to run this directory comparison between two versions of a directory, or an older version and the working copy, which is really awesome at times.

Unfortunately, not everything is in SVN.  I've got a Git-versioned project that contains a large folder with well over 100 auto-generated files.  They got regenerated recently, and TortoiseGit is telling me that every last one of them has been changed.  When I diff a few of them, though, all I see are harmless and irrelevant whitespace changes.  It's not impossible that a very few changes might exist somewhere in there, but I'd prefer not to have to go over every single one of them manually.

Is there any way I can get TortoiseGit to send a directory compare to BC for me, so I can have it compare the old version with my working copy while ignoring whitespace (it can do that) and then I can know for sure whether there are any relevant changes in this folder or if I can just revert the whole thing?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same problem. Unfortunately, as Yue Lin Ho stated, TortoiseGit does not have this available directly in the GUI. However, if you have TortoiseGit, you have some version of command line Git installed. Therefore, you can invoke BeyondCompare from the command line.

The following instructions assume you have Git version 2.2.0 or later

First, you have to setup BC as your diff tool:

```
  git config --global merge.tool bc
  git config --global mergetool.bc.path "c:/Program Files (x86)/Beyond Compare 4/bcomp.exe"
```

(Note that the default Windows path is shown. The path may be different if using a different OS or if you have a Portable version of BC installed on Windows, for example. Make sure you use the actual path to your copy of BC)

Then you can invoke BC folder compare in Git by running the following inside the folder for your Git project:

```
git difftool --dir-diff
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to send a directory compare to BC/external diff tool.

But, you still can compare two commits/revisions of a directory in TortoiseGit and there are some "ignore" options:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could try another approach with a temporary checkout:

Checkout your old version to a new directory.
Then use the standard folder comparison of beyond compare to compare the new directory with the working dirctory.

You can [define unimportant text](http://www.scootersoftware.com/support.php?zz=kb_unimportantv3) to filter the irrelevant whitespace changes.

When you finished your comparison you can delete the directory with the old version.